# macOS - Programmatically display an image using NSImageView

Tags: swift, macos, nsimageview

Using a Swift app targeting the macOS platform, I am trying to programmatically create an NSImageView object, assign an image to it, and then display it, using:

```
let imageViewObject = NSImageView();
let img = NSImage(cgImage: winCGImage, size: NSZeroSize);
imageViewObject.image = img
self.window.contentView?.addSubview(imageViewObject)
```

However, no image is displayed when I run this.
On the debugger, I can see that `imageViewObject.image` (i.e. `img`) has a valid image, and I can view it using the eye icon.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an image view with a **zero** frame, first create the image and then the view passing the proper size.

```
let img = NSImage(cgImage: winCGImage, size: NSZeroSize)
let imageViewObject = NSImageView(frame: NSRect(origin: .zero, size: img.size))
imageViewObject.image = img
```

Avoid to create views with the default initializer `()`.